# Function is not being called as it should in React onClick()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, i created a button to call a function when the button is clicked, it's working, the console.log() shows the message "Working", but the script inside it, it's not being shown on the browser. I have no idea what's wrong, could someone help me? I'm very new in Software Engineer and started learning React a few days ago, so i dont know too much about it.

This is the entire code:

```
class QuizGame extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        questions: Questions
    }

}

Game() {
    const { questions } = this.state;
    const item = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];
    const items = [item.a, item.b, item.c, item.d];
    console.log('Working');
    return (
        <div>
            <GameParagraph value={item.ques} />
            {
                items.map(quest => (
                    <div key={quest}>
                        <div>
                            <GameButton 
                                value={quest}
                                onClick={() => {
                                    if(item.ans === quest) {
                                        return console.log('Working');
                                    } else {
                                        return console.log('not working')
                                    }
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}


render() {
    return (
        <StartGame 
            onClick={() => this.Game()}
        />
    );
}
```

}

And that's the button to call the Game():

```
class StartGame extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Start</button>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: this.Game() is not bindend inside the react object

Comment: Inside the constructor, you should have `this.Game = this.Game.bind(this);`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i have already tried this and it didn't work :(. I really have no idea what's going on

Comment: returning from event handler won't work, either you will have to store data in some variable and show on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refactor your code.  Returning JSX from an event handler (which is what your function `Game` is) won't cause your component to render.

Instead, the "React" way to handle this is to provide some state variable that can be updated by the super class to cause a render. i.e.

```
class QuizGame extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
             started: false,
             questions: Questions
        }

    }

    startGame() { // JavaScript functions should be camelCase
        this.setState({started: true});
    }


    render() {
        if (this.state.started) {
            return const { questions } = this.state;
            const item = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];
            const items = [item.a, item.b, item.c, item.d];

            return (
                <div>
                    <GameParagraph value={item.ques} />
                        {items.map(quest => (
                            <div key={quest}>
                                <div>
                                    <GameButton 
                                        value={quest}
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            if(item.ans === quest) {
                                                return console.log('Working');
                                            } else {
                                                return console.log('not working')
                                            }
                                        }}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                </div>);
        } else {
            return <StartGame onClick={() => this.startGame()} />;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I was searching for!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
class QuizGame extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            questions: Questions,
            hasGameStarted: false
        }
    
    }
    
    Game() {
        const { questions } = this.state;
        const item = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];
        const items = [item.a, item.b, item.c, item.d];
        console.log('Working');
        return (
            <div>
                <GameParagraph value={item.ques} />
                {
                    items.map(quest => (
                        <div key={quest}>
                            <div>
                                <GameButton 
                                    value={quest}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        if(item.ans === quest) {
                                            return console.log('Working');
                                        } else {
                                            return console.log('not working')
                                        }
                                    }}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    startGameClicked() {
       this.setState({hasGameStarted: true});
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <StartGame 
                onClick={this.startGameClicked}
            />
           {this.state.hasGameStarted ? this.Game() : null}
    
        );
    }
```

Make sure you are binding the onClick event in StartGame component properly.